# How to eliminate Non-Trainable params in Deep Learning

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, rnn

First of all, I would like to know what is the cause of Non-Trainable parameters?
Secondly, how do you eliminate them?

I used a combined CNN-RNN, it returned that 130 Non-Trainable parameters.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here I assume that with "non-trainable parameters" you refer to what Keras says in the output of its `model.summary()`.

**You don't eliminate non-trainable parameters, because they are non-trainable for a reason**, and they are needed by the model or by the optimizer. Some examples of non-trainable parameters are:

- Pre-trained embedding matrices, which are loaded at the beginning and then frozen, and do not change during the training.
- Statistics parameters from batch normalization layers, that are updated but not during backpropagation.